# uniqness insertion in native xml database

Tags: xquery, sedna, nativexml

I am developing a project based on XML. I use the Sedna database to store my collection (which contains XML files, and their XSD schema files).

I define the primary/unique keys in those schemes, but till now I can insert duplicate values (via XQuery update insert command) into primary key field.

Comment: How is XSD schema imported into your XQuery or  database?
I thought that the Sedna is not schema-aware.

Comment: I loaded the file as follow: from cmd : " se_term -file load_data.xquery mydatabase"    and this file contains:                                             CREATE COLLECTION "mycol"&
 LOAD "1t.xml" "1" "mycol"&
 LOAD "2.xml" "2" "mycol"&
LOAD "1.xsd" "1schem" "mycol"&
LOAD "2.xsd" "2schem" "mycol"&

Comment: Dear Jens, you are right it is not schema aware and I have to implement unique index using triggers, but I don't know how to do that if you have any idea,would you help me please. till now I am learning how to write xQuery trigger before insert and I have to run this query in Sedna (I use Sedna .net driver), then how I can insert a node and check its sub-node value uniqueness??

Comment: Could you please [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41141317/edit) your question?

Answer (score 2):

To guarantee uniqueness constraint you should create BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH NODE trigger on proper path. In the trigger action the `$NEW` transitive variable can be used to fetch the new key and check if it already exists in the document (see [examples](http://sednadb.com/progguide/ProgGuidesu9.html#x15-600002.6.1) in the manual). To raise error [fn:error](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-error) function can be used.

Take the following note regarding triggers:

1. "It  is prohibited to use prolog in statements of the trigger action" — Sedna Programmer's Guide, [XQuery Triggers](http://sednadb.com/progguide/ProgGuidesu9.html#x15-590002.6).
2. See also [bug 51](https://sourceforge.net/p/sedna/bugs/51/) (although, already closed).