# load xsd files into Sedna db and insert unique elements into them

Tags: xquery, xquery-update, sedna

kindly note that I am developing an academic project based on Sedna database 3.5, I have a database which should contains of 4 XML files each one have its own schema file,
First question: how can I load those XSD files?? I had tried to load a collection which contains XML and XSD files, but I figured the collection is for one schema for all files, and I have a different schema for each file, Now, I am trying to load my xml documents from my .net application (not from cmd.exe) while I use Sedna .net API, I use Sedna upload function like:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
session.LoadDocument("doc1.xml","doc1.xml");
```

BUT what can I do for their xsd files???

The second Question: after I load xsd files correctly I have a query that insert a new node on some file, but I consider primary/unique key in my schema, but if I am right Sedna doesn't care about uniqueness, So I have to create a trigger before insert to check if the inserted value already exist, haven't I? if so, how can I implement this trigger and when to call it (if I build it in my .net application, it will be created each time I run the application??)

please advice

Comment: It seems that this question is duplicate of your [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141317/uniqness-insertion-in-native-xml-database) one. Why don't you just update the original question?